# Is adding a source to main run loop will affect main application operations?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-foundation

I am using `CFMessagePort` for interprocess communication in AppKit-based application and adding `CFMessagePort` source to the current run loop.

```
CFMessagePortRef local = CFMessagePortCreateLocal( kCFAllocatorDefault, daemonHostName,didReceiveDataFromOtherProcess, NULL,false);
if (local) {
    CFRunLoopSourceRef source = CFMessagePortCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, local, 0);
    CFRunLoopRef rl = [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] getCFRunLoop];
    CFRunLoopAddSource(rl, source, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
}
```

1. Is this is right approach?
2. Should i run runloop using `CFRunLoopRun()`?
3. **Is this will affect my main application operations(if client will
   send message in every 1second)?**

Comment: You can use `CFRunLoopGetCurrent()` instead of getting it via the `NSRunLoop`; they're equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, now i am using CFRunLoopGetMain().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I don't see anything wrong with it.
2. I take it from your comment that you are using the main run loop, which is run automatically, so the answer is No. If you did not create the run loop, you most definitely don't need to run it.
3. One time per second is not a problem at all. However if `didReceiveDataFromOtherProcess()` callback takes significant time to run, your interface will be less responsive. In that case, creating a secondary thread with its own run loop will help. If you're not sure, dont worry about this problem until you have it.

P.S. You should release the source after adding it, because it has been retained by the run loop.

Comment: sometimes my application is going in "not responding" mode.